# Chrome App Extension not working with Oauth Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setBadgeText' of undefined "

This is my code below:

This used to work in Chrome 27.0, but now with Chrome 29.0 it seems to have stopped functioning.  I'm not sure if it's this or the.. manifest.json file which loads this in the background.

```
  var DOCLIST_SCOPE = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds';
  var DOCLIST_FEED = DOCLIST_SCOPE + '/default/private/full/';
  var docs = []; // In memory cache for the user's entire doclist.
  var refreshRate = localStorage.refreshRate || 300; // 5 min default.
  var pollIntervalMin = 1000 * refreshRate;
  var requests = [];

  var oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
    'request_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
    'authorize_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
    'access_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken',
    'consumer_key': 'anonymous',
    'consumer_secret': 'anonymous',
    'scope': DOCLIST_SCOPE,
    'app_name': 'App Name'
  });

  function setIcon(opt_badgeObj) {
    if (opt_badgeObj) {
      var badgeOpts = {};
      if (opt_badgeObj && opt_badgeObj.text != undefined) {
        badgeOpts['text'] = opt_badgeObj.text;
      }
      if (opt_badgeObj && opt_badgeObj.tabId) {
        badgeOpts['tabId'] = opt_badgeObj.tabId;
      }
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText(badgeOpts);
    }
  };

  function clearPendingRequests() {
    for (var i = 0, req; req = requests[i]; ++i) {
      window.clearTimeout(req);
    }
    requests = [];
  };

  function logout() {
    docs = [];
    setIcon({'text': ''});
    oauth.clearTokens();
    clearPendingRequests();
  };
```

Comment: If you think the manifest could be the problem, why didn't you include it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is based off of the [OAuth tutorial](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html),
the problem is most likely due to http://crbug.com/310870, which is a bug in the samples. (The samples worked before because of a bug in Chrome.)

Make sure that any resources in your extension that are part of the OAuth flow are included in the "web_accessible_resources" key of the manifest. In the case of the contacts sample, this fragment needs to be included.

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "chrome_ex_oauth.html",
    "chrome_ex_oauthsimple.html"
],
```